# tip the hat -- what exactly does that mean? (context: helicopters)

Tags: meaning

From the action movie [San Andreas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Andreas_%28film%29) (2015) starring Dwayne Johnson as the main character.

A rescue team in a helo with a bunch of reporters on board making a documentary about the dangers of rescue operations are flying to save a girl who is hanging on a cliff in her car and is about to go down. But the problem is that the location is very difficult to get at because the car is stuck in a narrow ravine. So, they need to tilt their helicopter and somehow squeeze it into this narrow ravine so that they can get closer to her and take her up. Here's what they say:

> — Man, I don't see a way in.
>   — We're gonna **tip the hat**.
>   — Tip the hat?
>   — Yeah. You might wanna hold on to something. Here we go.

I presume this is a slang term that only search and rescue professionals use. *Tip* obviously means *to tilt*, but what is *hat* supposed to mean?

The stills from the movie:

[image: Helicopter descending]
[image: Helicopter banking]
[image: Helicopter angled sharply down]

Comment: Just a guess, but the tilt of the helicopter in steep descent resembles the tilt of a tipped hat: http://alexanderhats.com/sites/all/themes/images/hat_tip.jpg

Comment: Late 19th century (originally denoting an act of raising one's hat as a polite greeting or salutation): from the phrase, _tip one's hat_. I'm unsure if it's genuine helicopter pilot jargon but that's what the manoeuvre refers to.

Comment: Well , I haven't ever come across such thing I'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joe Dark is correct to say that when all men wore hats, it was polite to tip (remove the hat briefly) to show respect to someone.

The phrase *tip one's hat* is now an [idiom](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idiom) and simply means to show someone respect, often in recognition of an achievement (but does not involve an actual hat). An example:

> I'm impressed by your use of English. I tip my hat to you.

The phrase *tip the hat* as used in the film isn't an idiom, as it is not well established. It is a [metaphor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metaphor).

**In this case the *hat* being tipped is a helicopter.**

Bascially, *tip the hat* in this context means the helicopter is being tilted at an extreme angle.